# Cannot call transaction processor function within another transaction processor function

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

**Problem:** I cannot seem to call another transaction processor function using the Factory from within a transaction processor function.

**Scenario:** I have a transaction processor function as follows:

```
/**
 * Perform a deposit or withdrawal from a bank account
 * @param {org.acme.auctionnetwork.AccountTrx} transaction
 * @transaction
 */

function execTrx(transaction) {   
// do stuff
}
```

I want to call the above function in another transaction processor function:

```
/**
 * The buyer pays the listing price agreed to the seller and ownership of the vehicle transfers
 * @param {org.acme.auctionnetwork.PayListing} payment - pay the listing
 * @transaction
 */

function payListing(payment) {

    var factory = getFactory();

    var debitBuyer = factory.newResource('org.acme.auctionnetwork', 'AccountTrx', '##INSERTRANDOMTRXIDHERE##');
        debitBuyer.amount = payment.vehicleListing.buyerPrice;
        debitBuyer.operation = 'W';
        debitBuyer.account = buyerAccount;
        debitBuyer.party = buyerAccount.owner;

    var creditSeller = factory.newResource('org.acme.auctionnetwork', 'AccountTrx', '##INSERTRANDOMTRXIDHERE##');
        creditSeller.amount = payment.vehicleListing.buyerPrice;
        creditSeller.operation = 'D';
        creditSeller.account = sellerAccount;
        creditSeller.party = sellerAccount.owner;

    return getTransactionRegistry('org.acme.auctionnetwork.AccountTrx')
    .then(function(regTransactions) {
        return regTransactions.add(debitBuyer)
        .then(function() {
            return regTransactions.add(creditSeller);
        })
    });
}
```

However, the above complains that getTransactionRegistry() is not defined.  I'm aware when you typically create assets and participants that you would call the corresponding getAssetRegistry() or getParticipantRegistry() functions and call the add() function to update the registry with these new assets and participants.  The problem is I can't find how to call a transaction.

For research, I referenced https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/jsdoc/module-composer-runtime.Factory.html.  The newResource() function claims it works for assets, participants and transactions but I can't find sample code to execute transactions (looked in the default Hyperledger Composer demos as well).

I also did some troubleshooting and noted that even though I created a new instance of the AccountTrx transaction, the execTrx() function wasn't being called at all.

**Update:**  On further inspection, there appears to be a TransactionHandler class detailed here https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/jsdoc/TransactionHandler.html but for the life of me, I can't find any documentation on how to use it, or sample code.

Comment: You can't do what you want to do. A transaction processor can call other functions to allow for code modularisation but it will only be registered as a single transaction request in the transaction registry

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Doesn't this defeat the purpose of smart contracts where logic autonomously executes given a certain event?  In the car auction demo, what I was trying for was have a trx function close a listing, then call another trx function to exchange tokens between buyer/seller. If I'm not able to invoke subsequent transactions automatically, these would have to be invoked externally through calls via the RESTful API (e.g. node app or JS frontend web page).  Perhaps I'm missing the point, but thanks for confirming that it's at least technologically impossible at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its too late to answer this, but now, we can use getNativeAPI() to use some of the API's of Hyperledger fabric inside composer. We can use that inside one function to invoke the same network but it is another transaction.

In the below given link procedure, change the chaincode name (other-tutorial-network) to the same network name to call itself.
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/invoke-composer-network

API's available to be used with getNativeAPI() : https://fabric-shim.github.io/release-1.3/fabric-shim.ChaincodeStub.html?redirect=true